# How do I set the font size of text in a title bar in ST2?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How do I set the font size of text in a title bar in ST2?

I've tried the 'style' attribute but that affects the text of buttons in the toolbar too and they are then rendered smaller if the font-size is smaller.  I only want to set the text of the caption within the toolbar not everything including the buttons.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Try [styleHtmlCls](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-styleHtmlCls).

Comment: Yes this worked quite nicely thanks. If you add as answer I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titlebar has a config named [styleHtmlCls](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-styleHtmlCls) that should let you define a class to be applied to the content. You need to have `styleHtmlContent` set to true.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
title: '<div style="font-size: 30px; color: orange;">Title</div>',
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#z3f7e)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best way of doing this but you can try this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Cool Story Bro',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'MyButton'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        align: 'right',
                        text: 'MyButton1'
                    }
                ],
                listeners: [
                    {
                        fn: function(element, options) {
                            Ext.getCmp(element.id).titleComponent.innerElement.dom.style.color = 'red';
                            Ext.getCmp(element.id).titleComponent.innerElement.dom.style.fontSize = '30px';
                            Ext.getCmp(element.id).titleComponent.innerElement.dom.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
                        },
                        event: 'painted'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Demo: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#m3ilK#ArrdD

Comment: This will affect the layout of your titlebar. As you can see, the title is no longer vertically aligned.